# Updating from fault with AFIncrementalStore

Tags: ios, core-data, afincrementalstore

I have a project using AFIncrementalStore for syncing to a REST API. Let's say I have a simple 1 to many relationship set up where a Store has many Departments.

I have restful endpoints:
/Stores/:id (Returns only data about the store, no nested resources)
/Stores/:id/Departments

and a Store and Department models in CoreData with a 1 to many "departments" relationship on Store.

Let's say I'm populating a tableView that shows all departments for a particular store. If I have a store object and call store.departments I will then fault on the relationship, triggering an async request to /Stores/:id/Departments.

This will call AFIncrementalStore::newValueForRelationship to handle the fault which does not fire any notifications I can listen for to update the table once the request is finished. What's an appropriate way to update the table once the request has returned without reloading the view?

Answer (score 0):

You should populate your tableView using an NSFetchedResultsController. This way you will get notified when new objects that match your predicate are created / uptdated.